# Custom Button to update records later on a scheduled time

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button

I wanted to check if it is possible to build a custom button with the logic that which update the records after the specified time. Say for example if the users are adding the set of contacts to a campaign from the Report through Add Campaign button it should run only after 8PM. We have issues that users are trying to add the contacts to campaign in the regular hours which is causing deadlock on contacts that it cannot be used by the others users in cases creation and all. Wanted to check if there is a wy even though they add the contacts to Campaign it should run only after 8PM EST like that.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated, kind of stuck with this issue

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

1. Custom button updates Contact record with a custom field called `Add_to_Campaign_Scheduled_Action_Reference_Datetime__c`. This field is coerced to always be a value from 2000h-2359h of the same day that the button was clicked

   - Coercion can be done via a Flow or, perhaps more easily with a trigger.
   - You can spread the values out across the 240 minutes to minimize bach size
2. Then, use a record-triggered Flow with scheduled paths to execute at +0 hours from the `Add_to_Campaign_Scheduled_Action_Reference_Datetime__c`. The Flow paths do the work you need done to add to the campaign.

So, during the course of the day, as users click the button, you essentially are adding Time-based workflow entries for Flow Interviews (the paths) to run. Depending on how you spread the values, you could have up to 240 different flow executions, each with small batches.

Comment: Awesome Thanks a ton.. Happy to see there is a way to do this. You know if there are any articles on the Coercion, which can be referred to?

Comment: in apex, you can use this https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5198adbdbbeddf9726000700 to generate random numbers between two integers (1200 and 1359) - then add to today's datetime as of 0000h